# How can I get a stable 12V output from a motorcycle battery?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter, battery-operated

How can I get a stable 12VDC output from my motorcycle battery that is 12V but also connected to the alternator.  When riding the bike the voltage changes anywhere between 12V and 14.5V depending on RPM of the engine, which causes a problem to. I would also like to have it keep 12V even if the source voltage dips below 12V (not much, something like 11-11.5V for a short amount of time 5-10 seconds.)

Is there anything that can do this for me?

Comment: You're looking for something along the lines of a buck-boost regulator which is rugged enough (mechanically and electrically) for automotive applications. Unfortunately, shopping questions are not well-suited for this site, because we expect questions and answers to remain useful to future readers while products and availability change fairly regularly.

Comment: As well as a buck-boost function you probably should seek out a circuit (or product) that incorporates battery protection to remove the load when the battery voltage drops below some threshold.

Comment: If you don't need more than 30W, a "charging block" with a USB-C "power delivery" output and an appropriate "trigger cable" will give you a regulated 12V supply. Google for "USB C trigger cable".

Comment: depending on current needs, it might be cheaper/better to boost to 15v, throw a bunch of different caps on the output, then use an LDO or 7812 to drop to 12v. That should block more noise and provide a smoother output than an entry-level buck+boost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there anything that can do this for me?*

An appropriately designed buck-boost switching regulator can do this. It can be designed to produce a regulated output voltage of 12 volts from an input supply range of just a few volts to well over 12 volts.

Of course it needs to be robust for your application (automotive) and should be naturally capable of withstanding voltage surges of up to 100 volts.

Something like this (but with ruggedization to cope with automotive surges): -

[image]

Image from [Analog Device's website](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm8054.html).